# How to tag data from one model to a separate controller in ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, tags, seed

Problem:
I am trying to create an app whereby a person can 'click' on tag buttons that are of different sports preferences (ie: "Running", "Involves Bats"), each of which are tagged to certain sports. So, if the user selects the tag "Involves Bats", then the app will generate all associated sports such as "Baseball", which would have "Involves Bats" as a pre built tag.

What I've Done So Far:
I have added the acts_as_taggable gem
I have created a model for "Sports", that has no controller.
I have in seeds.rb created defined the "Sports" model with names of each sport.
I have a Users controller, where someone can submit email which takes to them to the their user page.

What is Left
I need to tag all preferences (ie "Running") to all potential "Sports". I am having a really difficult time doing this.
I also need to on the Users Page, show the tags ("Running") from which to choose.
I need to let User select the tags, and then generate the recommendations of Sports based on the associated tags

I know this is a fairly complex question, but I believe is a fairly common/basic app to build.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should check out Railscast episode #382 on tagging: it shows exactly what you need!
http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging